# Les mots « atterrissage », « amerrissage », « alunissage »

Tags: vocabulaire, néologismes

En français il n’y a pas de mot univoque signifiant « atteindre la surface extérieure d’un corps ».
On utilise « atterrissage » lorsqu’il s’agit d’une arrivée sur la terre, « amerrissage » lorsqu’on touche l’eau après un vol, et « alunissage » quand on atteint la lune.

Quel mot emploie-t-on pour exprimer l’arrivée sur mars ? Un « amarsissage » ? Les fusées qui partent de la terre et atteignent une lune de Jupiter, font-elles des « acallistossages ? »
Exprimé de façon plus succincte, ces expressions peuvent-elles être prolongées à des corps quelconques ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Un engin peut « se poser » sur n'importe quoi. Sur la terre, sur l'eau, sur la Lune ou sur Mars. Par extension, *atterrir* est aussi possible dans bien des cas, pourvu que le sol soit dur. Mais c'est vrai qu'« atterrir sur du métal » laisse un arrière gout de contradiction, car *atterrir* vient de *terre* (le sol) et non de la *Terre* (notre planète).

Le termes « [alunissage](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/alunissage) » et « [amarsissage](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/amarsissage) » ont déjà été maintes fois employés, mais ce n'est pas recommandé par l'Académie pour la raison énoncée plus haut (*atterrir* ne fait pas référence à l'astre ou la planète). Elle recommande donc « atterrir » sur Mars, sur la Lune, ou sur une planète inconnue.

Autrement, dans la même veine « acallistossage » fera surement sourire, mais sera très bien compris dans un contexte approprié¹ ! Tu peux donc laisser cours à ton imagination si tu le souhaites, quitte à vexer un peu l'Académie.

—
 <sup>1. Je veux dire par là qu'il faut quand même préparer un peu le *terrain* ;-)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Le terme « atterrissage » peut s’employer dans le cas général. Un extrait du [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/atterrissage) :

> Action de prendre contact avec le sol

Answer (score 1):

L'essentiel a été dit, notamment au sujet d'*atterrir* ayant un usage élargi, mais on peut noter également que dans bien des cas où aucun des termes spécifiques (voir titre de la question) n'est adapté, ou lorsque pour d'autres raisons on veut éviter de l'employer (comme par exemple pour éviter une répétition, ou bien si la nature de l'endroit est inconnue, etc.), on emploie l'autre verbe d'action possible : **se poser**. (voir [ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poser), section I.B.2.c)

(Cela dit, quand elle est possible, je trouve que la voie du néologisme est ici excellente.)