# Stagnation de la langue après une évolution technique

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Jadis, l’installation d’une barre pour empêcher l’utilisation d’une porte, notamment la porte d’entrée d’une maison, était commune. Désormais, la plupart des maisons sont équipées d’une serrure, qui requiert l’usage d’une clef pour déverrouiller de l’extérieur, souvent aussi pour verrouiller.

Si désormais dans la Francophonie en général, on ferme sa porte à clé, au Québec, on barre encore sa porte, en dépit de l’évolution de la technique de blocage. On pourrait dire que la langue n’a pas suivi la technologie.

Cet exemple est assez localisé, mais je suppose qu’il doit en exister d’autres, certains régionaux, mais peut-être aussi d’autres d’usage plus universel; certains très anciens, mais d’autres probablement récents.

En cherchant un peu, j’ai trouvé les verbes **embarquer** et **débarquer**, initialement les actions de monter à bord ou de descendre d’une barque. À mesure que les bateaux se firent plus grands, on persista avec ces verbes. Éventuellement, ces verbes s’appliquèrent aussi pour désigner les montées et descentes de tout type de véhicule, même terrestre ou aérien.

Ces histoires de véhicules me menèrent par la suite à la notion d’atterissage, qui inclut le mot *« terre »* dans sa formation, et a jusqu’au milieu du XXe siècle suffi à décrire tous les types d’arrivées sur un sol solide jusqu’alors expérimentées par l’humain. Lorsque certains corps célestes furent visités, par des sondes spatiales au début, puis par des humains, on commença à se demander si *« atterrissage »* était vraiment le mot qui convenait, d’où l’apparition dans la langue française du concept d’alunissage. L’Académie française et l’Académie des sciences blâment cette néologie, et je ne peux personnellement qu’approuver cette opinion. Si l’on s’engageait dans cette voie, nous aurions bientôt des termes ultra-spécialisés comme *avénussir* ou *aplutonnissage*, ou alors des termes plus génériques comme *aplanètissage* ou *acomètir*. Il convenait probablement en ce cas que la langue ne suive pas la technologie.

Je serais curieux de connaître d’autres exemples de mots ou d’expressions qui n’expriment plus forcément la réalité technologique qui a originellement présidé à leur création.

Comment: À propos d'atterrissage: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9615/les-mots-atterrissage-amerrissage-alunissage

Comment: Pas pour répondre à votre question intéressante (avec d’autres exemples de ce phénomène), mais  seulement pour mentionner [“assolir-assolissage”](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/assolir) comme synonyme de [*atterrir*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/synonymie/assolir/verbe) (peut-être moins spécifique si sa racine “sol” ne veut dire que “sol de la Terre”).  (even if it is a word, I think I’d be afraid to use it from fear of it being mistaken for something to do with “a**hole” in English: “Le pilote se prépare à nous assolir”!)

Comment: @PapaPoule Je n'avais jamais rencontré ces termes. Merci d'avoir pris le temps de les mentionner. Regarding the forms *“a-objectName-issage”*, Quebecquers would probably also find *a**callis**tissage* pretty funny for Callisto...

Comment: The early origins of people "listening to the TV/ecouter la tele" probably can be attributed to this phenomenon at a time when TVs were replacing many radios as home entertainment, but I think the fact that many people still use "listen/ecouter" instead of the readily available (and arguably more logical) "watch/regarder" (in both languages) is more a function of some kind of tradition and/or personal preference than language stagnation (but if I'm wrong, I think it's proof that language stagnation can lead to colorful and interesting ways of expressing things!).

Comment: Je ne vois pas comment cette question peut être autre chose qu'une collection sans fin de mots. [Ce n'est pas une réponse qu'il lui faut](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), mais un dictionnaire.

Comment: @Gilles Je conçois que le rythme des réponses soumises montre bien qu'il existe beaucoup de ces cas. Je croyais qu'il y en aurait certes quelques-uns, mais sans doute pas autant. J'ai néanmoins peu de regrets d'avoir demandé cette question, fut-elle mauvaise selon les critères de SE. Une belle récolte de propositions en peu de temps. Il me restera à savoir ce qui fait que les usagers collent à certains mots et lèvent le nez sur d'autres, mais il serait dommage de modifier cette question et rendre décalées toutes les belles réponses déjà soumises. Ainsi soit-il.

Comment: Please see [my post on Meta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/707/are-potentially-high-view-counts-taken-into-consideration-when-deciding-whethe) regarding, among other things, why I have voted to reopen this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quand je prépare un ragoût, je le fais cuire à **feu** doux, même sur une plaque à induction.

Si j'ai un exposé à présenter, je prépare des **diapositives** et ce n'est pas un film argentique inversible.

À propos de **film**, ceux que je visionne sur mon écran à la maison n'utilisent plus le support historique (et les super-8, qui sont bien des **films**, ne sont plus visionables sans de gros efforts de copie numérique).

Toujours dans les supports audiovisuels, la plupart des **disques** d'or ou de platine ne représentent plus des ventes de galettes vinyle ou CD.

Comment: On dit d'ailleurs encore qu'on va voir un *film* au cinéma, même si depuis le tournage jusqu'à la projection, il n'y a peut-être plus un seul *film* (au sens de pellicule) qui a été utilisé, tout pouvant se faire en digital.

Comment: @Greg Et on se demande quel rapport *digital* a avec les appendices d'une main.

Comment: La question ayant été mise en arrêt, je vote pour votre réponse, celle que j'ai préférée parmi toutes celles soumises. Merci à vous et à tous pour votre collaboration!

Answer (score 8):

Un **chauffeur** n'entretient plus le feu d'une machine à vapeur.

On ne **décroche** plus ni ne **raccroche** son combiné au crochet situé à droite de l'appareil téléphonique.

Comment: D'ailleurs qui se souvient que le _combiné_ fait référence à la réunion de l'écouteur et du microphone dans un seul ensemble préhensible? (voir [cette image](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bu1Q8JXCzGU/maxresdefault.jpg) pour un contre-exemple tiré de Mary Poppins)

Comment: @mouviciel Ah oui, j'y ai pensé en écrivant *combinés*. Les premiers modèles n'étaient pas loin des téléphones du type « pots de yaourt » ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Dans divers sports, les arbitres mettent toujours des *cartons* rouges, jaunes, etc. Mais en réalité, ces cartons ne sont plus faits en carton mais en matière plastique.

Un *verre* n'est plus nécessairement en verre. On peut utiliser un *verre en plastique*. Même chose pour des *verres de lunettes*: sur les lunettes bon marché, ils peuvent être en plastique.

Comment: Off topic: Les verres correcteurs "en plastique* (organiques) sont plus coûteux que les verres *en verre* (minéraux).

Answer (score 4):

Pour encore tourner autour du feu, *allumer* un appareil électrique vient d'allumer une lampe, qui déjà ne se fait plus avec du feu depuis bien longtemps.

Comment: Je me rends compte qu'*allumer* venant de *lumière*, c'est peut-être pas si reprochable, mais c'est quand-même bizarre de réduire tout appareil électrique à une lampe à notre époque.

Comment: Étant un travailleur de terrain, je passe une grande partie de ma vie sur des camps isolés, parfois fort rustiques. Allumer au sens propre un chauffe-eau, un rond de poêle ou même une lampe fait encore partie de mon expérience usuelle. Peut-être mon style de vie n'est pas exactement standard, par contre...

Answer (score 3):

La ***presse***, en cette ère numérique, ne fait plus guère appel aux ***presses*** lorsque vient le moment de mettre ***sous presse*** *(dans bien des cas, quelqu’un se contentera désormais de **presser** un bouton sur son clavier ou sa souris, et voilà l’article lancé sur le site web du journal)*.

Comment: I'm not sure if the best French translation of "Hot off the press/es" would even include the word "presse/s", but your answer makes me think of how that expression, in English at least, first got extended figuratively to other domains and now, even its use in its original context of print journalism is for the most part figurative!

Answer (score 2):

C’est **peut-être**  plutôt évidence de la stagnation du niveau de l’intelligence des élèves de ma femme  (institutrice de français dans un «middle school» ici en Virginie) qu’un exemple du phénomène dont vous parlez, ...

... mais quand elle attaque le sujet de «Quelle heure est-il?» avec  ses flèches de 12, 13 et même 14 ans, il lui faut d’abord leurs expliquer ce que ça veut dire (et d’où ça vient) **en anglais** la notion de

> « quarter/half past » et « quarter of »

en ce qui concerne  «telling time in English» avant qu’elle oserait introduire les notions de

> « et demie » et « et quart/moins le quart »

pour dire l’heure en français.

---

Bien-sur ce problème doit venir du fait que ces enfants ont grandi avec les montres et les écrans qui donnent l’heure précise et numériquement,

mais même la plupart de ceux qui connaissent les  horloges analogiques n’ont jamais appris à visualiser un cadran d'horloge comme une chose qui peut être divisée en quart ou en demi,

donc (avant leurs classe de français avec Madame MamaCoq!)  ils n’avaient jamais dit ces expressions de l’heure (même en anglais) et la plupart de ceux qui les ont entendues ne savaient même pas d’où elles venaient!

Comment: Je crois au contraire que c'est très près du phénomène dont je parlais: le cercle des anciennes horloges se divise instinctivement en quatre (ou en deux). Une unité se divisant en 100 sous-unités *(les devises par exemple)* se divisent elles aussi communément en quart *(du moins en anglais: a quarter = 25 cents)*. La division des heures et des minutes en 60 sous-unités, reliques d'un ancien type de division, rend peut-être la subdivision en 2 ou 4 moins intuitive sans le support visuel d'une horloge bien ronde?